# How do I get a HTML value from $form_state?

Tags: forms

I am dynamically showing the radio box values from database on a form.

```
<input id="edit-info-prog-dates-0" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="0" name="info[prog_dates]">
<label for="edit-info-prog-dates-0" class="option"><div class="test-cost-date">Aug 13, 2012 - Sep 24, 2012</div><div class="currency-w1"><span class="currency-symbol">$</span><span class="currency-cost">350.00</span> <span class="currency-code">CAD</span></div> </label>
```

I am using the following code to generate the above HTML.

```
 $form['info']['prog_dates'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select Dates'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $dates,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="radios-programdates">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

I want to save the value for the cost in database. If I write the following code, I am only getting the input value '0'.

```
$form_state['info']['prog_dates']
```

How do I fetch the cost value, which is inside the `<span>` and `<label>` in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

From the HTML you show, I get that the partial content of `$dates` is the following.

```
$dates = array(
  0 => '<div class="test-cost-date">Aug 13, 2012 - Sep 24, 2012</div><div class="currency-w1"><span class="currency-symbol">$</span><span class="currency-cost">350.00</span> <span class="currency-code">CAD</span></div>'
);
```

What you can do to get the 350.0 value is changing `$dates` to the following.

```
$dates = array(
  '350.0' => '<div class="test-cost-date">Aug 13, 2012 - Sep 24, 2012</div><div class="currency-w1"><span class="currency-symbol">$</span><span class="currency-cost">350.00</span> <span class="currency-code">CAD</span></div>',
  // ...
);
```

In that way, `$form_state['values']['info']['prog_dates']` would contain `'350.0'`, if the users select the radio button I shown.

From the HTML you shown, I get that in the form you set #tree to `TRUE`. Differently, the HTML name assigned to the radio form field would not be *info[prog_dates]* as in your case, but *prog_dates*. If I am wrong about that, it means you need to check the value of `$form_state['values']['prog_dates']`, instead of `$form_state['values']['info']['prog_dates']`.

Answer (score 0):

If `[info]` is a fieldset then to get the value of "prog_dates" you only need:

```
$form_state['values']['prog_dates']
```

Comment: It could be also `$form_state['values']['prog_dates']` if the form has #tree set to `TRUE`.